# destructuring props in component getting different result

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

New to react world, trying to learn destructuring, have been reading about it but stuck here,
if i do it like this function MList({action}) { // const data = [action];} i am just getting 'cameras'. So how to destructure and get same result as with props below
this is Mcard.js:

```js
            <Box pt={1}>
              <MList
                action="cameras"
              />
            </Box>
```

This is inside MList komponent:

i want to destructure this code ( works gives 'name' and 'ident'):

```js
function MList(props) {

 const initialize = () => {
const data = props[props.action];

if (!data || data.length < 1) {
  return;
}
data.map((e) => {
  collapseStates["" + e.name + e.ident] = false;
  return;
});
setCollapseS(collapseS);
  };

 }
```

Comment: No quite clear what you want to achieve? In `MList(props)` `props` is an `object`, which has property `action` which value is `cameras`. `MList({ action })` just destructures action from this object, so you dont have to use `props.action` all over you r component, this `props[props.action]` is the same as `props.cameras`,

Comment: these two are the same :  const data = props[props.action] and  const data = [action]  when destructured ?

Comment: no, `const data = [action]` creates array with "cameras" element, `props[props.action]` you try to access "cameras" property on props object like `props["cameras"]`

Comment: so how to change 'props[props.action]' when there is no 'props' word anymore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know React but destructuring the arguments should be something like the following

```js
function MList({action, ...tail}) {

    const initialize = () => {
        const data = tail[action];

        if (!data || data.length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        data.map(({name, ident}) => {
            collapseStates["" + name + ident] = false;
            return;
        });
        setCollapseS(collapseS);
    };

}
```

Also I would suggest using `data.forEach` instead of `data.map` if you don't need to save the result in another array

Answer (score 0):

Nikita is correct about using `props["action"]` or `props.action` to grab the values. But you can actually destructure the props right inside of the function declaration like so:

```
function MList({ action, ...other props }) {
    // Can now use action directly instead of props.action
}
```

It is also worth noting that array and object destructuring is not react specific, this is just how javascript works.

Edit: Accessing the action variable from here will give you "cameras" as a result because that is what you passed into the props

Comment: so this would be : function MList({ action, ...other props }) {

 const initialize = () => {
//const data = props[props.action];
data = [props.action];
if (!data || data.length < 1) {
  return;
}
data.map((e) => {
  collapseStates["" + e.name + e.ident] = false;
  return;
});
setCollapseS(collapseS);
  };

 } ??

Comment: No if you are destructuring the object then you don't need to use props at all. Just simply use: const data = action

Comment: could you possibly give an answer with my code corrected ?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to set the data variable to the value of the action prop?

Comment: just want to get rid of word 'props' that i dont need to write it everytime (thats what destructuring mean ...)

Comment: Yes then if you do what I have done above, then you do not need to use the word props anymore. Simply type action. It might be worth reading the documentation on destructuring if you still do not understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment